# Validation Rule for locking specific fields

Tags: validation-rule

I am looking to create a validation rule that if the checkbox "verified" (  Verified__c ) is checked then it locks these three fields,  Legal_Entity_Name__c ,  State_of_Registration_or_Incorportation__c , and   Legal_Entity_Type__c so they are read only to everyone but system admins.

Would it be something like:

```
myCheckbox__c = True && ISCHANGED(myTextField__c)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, that's most of the validation rule(s) you'd need.

Having errors appear next to fields (as opposed to at the top of the page) is generally better UX (user experience), so you'll likely want to make 3 validation rules (one for each field).

`<boolean/checkbox field> = true` can be reduced to simply `<boolean/checkbox field>`

You'll also need to add in the condition to exempt your sysadmins from the rule. `NOT($Profile.Name = 'System Administrator')` does the trick, though if there's a possibility that you'll expand that in the future then it'd be a good idea to use a [Custom Permission](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custom_perms_overview.htm&type=5) instead.

So you're looking at

```java
/* AND() is equivalent to && */
/* Which one you use is mostly personal preference */
/* Choose one and stick with it for consistency */
AND(
    /* Checkbox field is already boolean, so it can be used directly */
    Verified__c,
    ISCHANGED(your_target_field__c),
    /* Validation rules trigger when the overall result is TRUE */
    /* AND() returns TRUE only when all parts are TRUE */
    /* So if a Sysadmin makes an edit, this will evaluate to FALSE, */
    /*   making the entire AND() become FALSE, and allowing the edit */
    NOT($Profile.Name = 'System Administrator')
)
```

Comment: IMHO recommending a profile name check promotes bad practice. I was glad you mentioned custom permissions, though you really should have gone with that all the way instead of the anti-pattern of profile name checking. After all, this is exactly the sort of thing custom permissions are for.

Comment: @PhilW I was going to go off on how bad the UX is in actually assigning Custom Permissions, but I think I'm confusing that with assigning permission sets.

Comment: I appreciate the idea of seperate VRs to improve UX. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Assigning custom permissions is little different to assigning other system permissions and the like. If you changed the answer to cover this instead of the profile name check, I would upvote.